# Error while using express-session and express-socket.io-session NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express, express-session

I'm using nodejs express-session and express-socket.io-session, the problem is that when I run my server.js , there are some errors:

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option node_modules\express-socket.io-session\index.js:66:7
express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option node_modules\express-socket.io-session\index.js:66:7
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option node_modules\express-socket.io-session\index.js:66:7
```

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");
var app = express();

app.use(session({
   secret: 'ssshhhhh',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
   resave: true,
   secret: 'ssshhhhh',
   saveUninitialized: true
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log(socket.handshake.session);
});
```

I hope i have been clear on my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup doesn't look right, you want to define your session in such a way it can be shared across both express and socket.io e.g.

```
const session = require('express-session')({  
   secret: 'ssshhhhh',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
});
const sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
...
app.use(session);
io.use(sharedsession(session));
```

Comment: @ireeqhz answer still applies, your not passing a configured session into socket.io your passing a reference to the session constructor.